# Ecto Query Fragment with Postgres substring

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

**Scenario**
I need to sort the order from the database alpha then numeric.
So the order should look like `["A","B","C","1","2","3"]`

**Postgres**
This seems to work. I tried it out.

```
WITH x(t) AS (
    VALUES
     ('a')
    ,('3')
    ,('2')
    ,('1')
    ,('c')
    ,('b')
    )
SELECT t
FROM   x
ORDER  BY (
substring(t, '^[A-Za-z].*'),       -- cast to integer 
substring(t, '[^0-9_].*$'))        -- works as text
```

I'm using Ecto and from my understanding you need to use [`Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.2.6/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) in order to send commands to the database. So I wrote this.

**In Ecto**

```
def alphabetical(query) do
 from c in query, order_by: [fragment("substring(?, ?)", c.name, '^[A-Za-z].*'), fragment("substring(?, ?)", c.name, '[^0-9_].*$')]
end
```

**Error**
I'm getting this error in the app

```
ERROR 42883 (undefined_function): function pg_catalog.substring(character varying, integer[]) does not exist
```

**ANSWER**
Written in Ecto and using fragments

```
  def alphabetical(query) do
      from c in query, order_by: [fragment("? < 'a'", c.name)]
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not seem to be correct. Try this simple one:

```
SELECT t
FROM x
ORDER BY t < 'a', t
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b2e06d3ff619443b11aa1bf93f1c5c63)